# DataFrame Create new column after applying a function on groupby values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have such a dataframe :

[image: Original Dataframe]

With a minimal example :

```
d = {'Subject': [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 
    'Pattern': [1,1,2,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 
    'Time': [0.85, 0.92, 1.03, 1.06, 0.89, 0.85, 1.20, 1.03, 1.25, 100.03, 1.97,0.23,0.64]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Where `Subject` ranges from 1 to 8 and `Pattern` from 1 to 3. I want to create a new column where after grouping by `Subject` and `Pattern` I apply a function that removes outliers from the `Time` list associated to the groupby. Right now I have a solution that works well, but I was wondering if there would be a more elegant solution to it, so that I learn how to interact better with DataFrame. Taking the example, it should output :

```
 Subject Pattern Time Time_2
0   1      1    0.85    0.85
1   1      1    0.92    0.92
2   1      2    1.03    1.03
3   1      2    1.06    1.06
4   2      3    0.89    0.89
5   2      3    0.85    0.85
6   3      2    1.20    1.20
7   3      2    1.03    1.03
8   3      2    1.25    1.25
9   3      2    100.03  0.00 # <---
10  3      2    1.97    1.97
11  3      2    0.23    0.23
12  3      2    0.64    0.64
```

My current code :

```
def remove_outliers(arr):
    elements = np.array(arr)

    mean = np.mean(elements)
    sd = np.std(elements)
    
    return [x if (mean - 2 * sd < x <  mean + 2 * sd) else 0 for x in arr]

df_g = df.groupby(['Subject', 'Pattern'])['Time']

times = []
keys = list(df_g.groups.keys())
for i, l in enumerate(df_g.apply(list)):
    times.append((keys[i], remove_outliers(l)))
    
df['Time_2'] = 0
for k, l in times:
    vals = df[(df['Subject'] == k[0]) & (df['Pattern'] == k[1])].index.values
    df['Time_2'].iloc[vals] = l
```

Comment: Do you mind calling df.to_csv(index=False) so that we can start from the same df instead of copying an image of your df ?

Comment: Sure ! Just give me a moment.

Comment: Please share your data as code not image. Then you can add two columns wits mean and std using groupby and agg plus merge or transform. Finally you can use your condition with np.where or iloc.

Comment: What @fiphrelin suggests is to add the output of df.to_dict() to your question

Comment: Edited with a minimal example (instead of sharing the whole data which would be a mess)

Comment: There is an issue with your minimal example. The groups after grouping based on subject and pattern are actually the same number of rows as the df. which is to say, each group in your groupby has only a single row.

Comment: Can you post your desired resulting dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

1. Use groupby `transform` the groups to get GroupWise mean and std for each row.
2. Next use these series objects to create your `check` condition as per your function.
3. Next inverse this and use `df.mask` to mask values that lie outside this range, and fill them with 0 instead.

```
grouper = df.groupby(['Subject', 'Pattern'])['Time']

mean = grouper.transform('mean')
std = grouper.transform('std').fillna(0)

check = (df['Time'] < (mean - 2*std)) | (df['Time'] > (mean + 2*std))

df['Time_new'] = df['Time'].mask(check).fillna(0)
print(df)
```

```
    Subject  Pattern    Time  Time_new
0         1        1    0.85      0.85
1         1        1    0.92      0.92
2         1        2    1.03      1.03
3         1        2    1.06      1.06
4         2        3    0.89      0.89
5         2        3    0.85      0.85
6         3        2    1.20      1.20
7         3        2    1.03      1.03
8         3        2    1.25      1.25
9         3        2  100.03      0.00   #<---
10        3        2    1.97      1.97
11        3        2    0.23      0.23
12        3        2    0.64      0.64
```

> NOTE: Jsut to add the 3*std deviation condition is too high a range for your example. Try 2*std.

Comment: Seems to work nicely ! Thank you for the detailed explanation

Comment: Glad to help! Do note that for your example, try 2*std since 3*std is a larger range.